# How to make React-Material-UI Popper draggable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draggable, react-typescript, popper.js

I want to dynamically change [Popper](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/#popper) position on the screen with [react-draggable](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable).

Here's my code:

```
import PopupState, {bindPopper, bindToggle} from "material-ui-popup-state";

     ...
       return (
            <PopupState variant={"popper"} popupId='demo-popper'>
            {(popupState) => {
                // popupState.anchorEl = undefined <-- THIS WORKS BUT ERROR WITH 'anchorEl' IS RAISED
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" {...bindToggle(popupState)}>
                            Toggle Popper
                        </Button>
                        <Draggable defaultPosition={position}>
                            <Popper {...bindPopper(popupState)}
                                    transition
                                    className={classes.popper}
                                    placement='bottom-start'
                            >
                                <Paper elevation={5}>
                                    <Typography variant={"h2"} className={classes.typography}>
                                        POPUP BODY
                                    </Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </Popper>
                        </Draggable>
                    </div>
                )
            }}
        </PopupState>
      )
```

... and [CODE Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-popup-draggable-o1328?file=/src/TestPopup.js:0-2077)

As you can see, when I make `popupState.anchorEl = undefined` dragging functionality works, but error with `anchorEl` occurs.

> Failed prop type: Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
> It should be an HTML element instance or a referenceObject (https://popper.js.org/docs/v1/#referenceObject).

When `anchorEl` is set, `<Draggable>` is not working.
I think that on every component render, caused by dragging, `Popup`'s position is being changed, but it's immediately going back to default, due to set `anchorEl`

[Popper.js docs](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/)

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Comment: I changed the value of ```anchorEl``` from ```undefined``` to ```null```, and it works fine. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-popup-draggable-forked-np51p?file=/src/TestPopup.js) and [popup](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#simple-popover).

Comment: @Medi It works fine with `undefined` too, but the problem is warning in console after `Popup` creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Popper.
Just use the Draggable component with the Paper.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-popup-draggable-forked-lmylb